# Accessing temp files created by an application

Tags: rooting, file-system, temp-files

I have an application that I know writes temp files to the `data/data/app-package` directory. Using a file browsing app or windows explorer it seems these directories are sufficiently protected.

Is there a way for a power-user to access these files? Any unusual methods welcome.

So far it sounds like: Step 1 - root. Step 2 - ?, Step 3 - profit!

Comment: The `/data` partition on most Android devices is usually inaccessible without [tag:rooting].  You would need to post your device's make and model number for us to recommend the best rooting methods.

Comment: I have a moto g and samsung tab 3. Do you have general steps to root? I'm not necessarily interested in a device specific process, but more the possibility/general process of this.